# Removing double quotes during rendering of text file when the delimiter is a [TAB]

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportbuilder, power-bi-report-server

I am using PB Report Builder version 15.7.1806.11 and uploading the reports to PB Report Server,I have already modified the rsreportserver.config so that I can export as .txt using TAB as delimiter, **BUT** the problem is when a text field on a table has a space between words,
ie: `Cats and Dogs` will be exported as `"Cats and Dogs"`, how can I remove the quotations without changing the delimitier.

All the Data comes from an SQL Server Database

The solution of changing the delimiter to a pipe(or any other delimiter) "|" removes the quotations but, the desired output is a text file with a TAB delimiter and no quotation.